# Type error when processing graphql result

Tags: ocaml, graphql, reason, bucklescript, ppx

I just started playing with reasonML and graphql and have built a simple react component that retrieves data from a world cup API. My code is below:

```
[@bs.module] external gql: ReasonApolloTypes.gql = "graphql-tag";

module GetMatches = [%graphql
  {|
    query getMatches($id: ID!){
        matches(id: $id) {
            date
            homeTeam {name}
            awayTeam {name}
            homeScore
            awayScore
            goals {
              scorer {
                name
              }
              time
            }
          }
    }
  |}
];

module GetMatchesQuery = ReasonApollo.CreateQuery(GetMatches);

let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("Matches");

let make = _children => {
  ...component,
  render: _self => {
    let matchParam = GetMatches.make(~id="300331511", ());
    <GetMatchesQuery variables=matchParam##variables>
      ...{
           ({result}) =>
             switch (result) {
             | Loading => <div> {ReasonReact.string("Loading")} </div>
             | Error(error) =>
               <div> {ReasonReact.string(error##message)} </div>
             | Data(response) => <Matches matches=response##matches />
             }
         }
    </GetMatchesQuery>;
  },
};
```

Matches Component

```
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("Matches");

let make = (~matches, _children) => {
  ...component,
  render: _self =>
    <div>
      {
        matches
        |> Js.Array.map(match => <Match match key=match##id />)
        |> ReasonReact.array
      }
    </div>,
};
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
This has type:
    option(Js.Array.t(option({. "awayScore": option(int),
                               "awayTeam": option({. "name": option(string)}),
                               "date": option(string),
                               "goals": option(Js.Array.t(option({. "scorer": 
                                                                   option(
                                                                   {. "name": 
                                                                    option(
                                                                    string)}),
                                                                   "time": 
                                                                   option(
                                                                   string)}))),
                               "homeScore": option(int),
                               "homeTeam": option({. "name": option(string)})})))
  But somewhere wanted:
    Js.Array.t(Js.t(({.. id: string} as 'a))) (defined as array(Js.t('a)))
```

I added Js.log(response##matches); and got this in the console
[image: Js.log]

Comment: no id in query?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's some context missing here, and that you have something like `open Belt` at the top of your file.

The type error says `response##matches` is an `array` in an `option`, but also that the array elements themselves are in `option`s, which is super weird. So my theory is that the code generated by `graphql-ppx` uses something like array indexing, which translates to a call to `Array.get` that in the standard library throws an exception if out of bounds, but in `Belt`, and many other standard libraries replacements, returns an `option`.

This is one of many problems with using `ppx`s. It generates code not in isolation and can interact weirdly with the rest of your code, and it's not easy to debug.

Comment: I'm not using Belt anywhere, I added the Js.log value to the question to show what the result of the graphql query.

Comment: The result of the query doesn't matter (at least not at this point). This is a type error, not a runtime error. Do you open any other modules in this file?